# open website from Jar file

Tags: java, ioexception

I am still getting my feet wet with Java. So I'm not familiar with everything, so please excuse me if this is a rookie problem. To give you an overall outline of what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to make a `.jar` that opens up the users web browser and sends them to a website. Reason for this, I want to prank my friends during class. If you can imagine what websites I can send them too.

code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class webPrank {



public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{ 

    try {
         String url = "http://www.facebook.com";
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
       }
       catch (java.io.IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
}
}
```

Now I would understand if a computer doesn't allow this because of security reasons. But like I said before, I dont know if I'm doing something wrong. on PC I'm getting this error:
     `A Java Eception has occurred.`
and on a Mac I'm getting this error:
    `Check the Console for possible error messages.`

But it does work perfectly if I just hit `Run` on eclipse(Mac or PC), so I know my issues is coming from the `.jar`. or at least I think so.
Now am I doing something wrong when I export this as a `.jar` file? or is what I am trying to do not possible? Please let me know if you need any addition information. Thank you for your time!

Comment: what was the exception?

Comment: As a completely unrelated sidenote, you should start using the Java naming conventions from the get-go - they'll only help you in the future. Class names should be UpperCamelCase, as described here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367. Again, completely unrelated, but somewhat useful.

Comment: Does this have to be written in Java? You could achieve the same result much easier on Windows with a .cmd file with just one line:`start www.google.com`  You can probably do something similar with a .sh file on Mac too

Comment: @JoeBoyle I come from Objective-C, so I've just been used to typing my camel case like that, sorry.

Comment: @FabianBuentello It's completely fine. It's just recommended that you follow the conventions, as it'll make everything easier if/when you a) mix with other devs, or b) try to maintain larger projects... Language conventions suck to learn :P

Comment: @KevinHooke I don't think this is at all about language dependencies... He's learning the language, and likely just starting with something he thought would be fun or cool.

Comment: @KevinHooke, sorry I thought I pressed "Add Comment" on my response to you. But you gave me a great substitution for what I want to do. I'm just gonna do that! thanks!

Comment: No problem! Your Java code should do exactly the same too, so if it's not running as a jar we'd need to see a full stack trace to work out why it's not working, maybe remove the try/catch so we can see the exception stacktrace, or print the stacktrace instead of the message. Either way, sometimes the easiest solutions are the best :-)